# Problema con validacion de input vacios en formulario tipo wizard

Tags: javascript, php, html

tengo un problema que me esta explotando la cabeza. no puedo resolverlo y espero me puedan ayudar. resulta que estoy desarrolando un formulario tipo wizard con 4 section. el problema surge cuando quiero validar los input vacios por section. es decir que si en el paso uno algun campo este vacio no lo deje avanzar al siguiente paso hasta llenar todos los campos.

este es mi codigo

```
  <div class="wrapper">
        <form action="<?php echo base_url();?>aspirante/insertar/" method="POST" id="wizard" class="signup-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="form-total">
            <!-- SECTION 1 -->
            <h2>Personal Information</h2>
            <section>
                <div class="inner">
                <img class="imgLogo" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo/logoL2W.png'); ?>" width="380" height="130">
                <p class="text">Fill out this short form and<br>
                we will answer your request in<br> 1 hour </p>
                    <div class="image-holder">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/wizard/Montana_1.png'); ?>" width="90%" height="100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-content" >
                        <div class="form-header">
                            <h3>WHAT WE SHOULD<br> 
                            KNOW ABOUT YOUR INFORMATION? </h3>
                        </div>
                        <p style="top:150px;position:absolute;left:630px;color:black;">Please complete with your data</p><br><br>
                        
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" required placeholder="First Name" class="form-control2" name="fistName" id="fistName">
                                <label for="" style="color: red;">Debe de llenar los campos vacios</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" required placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control2" name="lastName" id="lastName">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="address" required placeholder="E-Mail" class="form-control2" name="mail" id="mail">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="number" required placeholder="Phone" class="form-control2" name="phone" id="phone">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-holder">
                            <div class="checkbox-circle mt-24" onclick = "noneSSN();" >
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkEIN" checked>Identification Number
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-holder" >
                            <div class="checkbox-circle mt-24" onclick="noneEIN();">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkSSN">Social Security Number
                                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-holder" id="check1" >
                            
                                <input type="number" placeholder="EIN" class="form-control2" name="ein" id="ein">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-holder" id="check2" style="display:none;">
                            
                                <input type="number" placeholder="SSN" class="form-control2" name="ssn" id="ssn">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- SECTION 2 -->
            <h2>Applicant Address</h2>
            <section>
                <div class="inner">
                <img class="imgLogo" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo/logoL2W.png'); ?>" width="340" height="130">
                <p class="text">Entre mas informacion nos<br>
                    proporciones para entender<br>
                    tu proyecto, mas rapido te<br>
                    podremos cotizar</p>
                    <div class="image-holder" >
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/wizard/Montana_1.png'); ?>" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-content">
                        <div class="form-header" >
                            <h3>Que tipo de<br>
                            industria trabajas?</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-header" >
                        <p >Esta informacion nos ayuda a entender mejor los<br>
                        requerimientos, ademas de mejorar nuestro servicio</p>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="grid" name="tipoIndustria" id="tipoIndustria">
                            <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Street" class="form-control2" name="street" id="street">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="City" class="form-control2" name="city" id="city">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="State" class="form-control2" name="state" id="state">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Zip Code" class="form-control2" name="zipcode" id="zipcode">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- SECTION 3 -->
            <h2>Work Information</h2>
            <section>
                <div class="inner">
                <img class="imgLogo" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo/logoL2W.png'); ?>" width="340" height="130">
                <p class="text">El cielo es el limite!<br>
                    contamos con la capacidad de<br>
                    producir el numero de piezas<br>
                    que necesitas para tu proyecto</p>
                    <div class="image-holder">
                        <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/wizard/Montana_1.png'); ?>" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-content">
                        <div class="form-header">
                            <h3>Cuantas piezas necesitas?</h3>
                        </div>
                        <p >Esto nos ayudara a dimensionar la carga de trabajo y el<br>
                        tiempo de entrega, no hay minimos ni maximos</p>
                        
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Legal Business Name" class="form-control2" name="businessName" id="businessName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-holder">
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Brand Name" class="form-control2" name="brandName" id="brandName">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!-- SECTION 4 -->
            <h2>Confirmation</h2>
            <section>
                <div class="inner">
                <img class="imgLogo" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/logo/logoL2W.png'); ?>" width="340" height="130">
                <p class="text">Si conoces el proceso<br>
                    avanza a la siguiente pregunta,<br>
                    nosotros te ayudaremos en<br>
                    este paso</p>
                    <div class="image-holder">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/wizard/Montana_1.png'); ?>" width="100%" height="100%" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-content">
                        <div class="form-header">
                            <h3>Que tipo de<br> 
                                proceso requieres?</h3>
                        </div>
                        <p style="top:130px;position:absolute;left:585px;text-align:center;font-size:15px;color:black;">No te preocupes si no conoces, nosotros asesoramos<br>
                        y sugerimos el que mejor se adapte a tu<br>
                        proyecto</p>
                        
                        <div class="grid" id="tipoProceso">
                        
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
        </form>
```

este es mi JS

```
$(function(){

$("#form-total").steps({
    headerTag: "h2",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "fade",
    enableAllSteps: true,
    transitionEffectSpeed: 500,
    labels: {
        current: ''
    },
    
    onFinished: function(event, currentIndex) {
        $("#wizard").submit();
    }, 
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) { 
    
    fistName = document.getElementById("fistName").value;
    lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    mail = document.getElementById("mail").value;
    phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
    street = document.getElementById("street").value;
    //la condición
    if (fistName.length == 0) {
        alert("First Name Required");
        return false;
    }
    if (lastName.length == 0) {
        alert("Last Name Required");
        return false;
    }
    if (mail.length == 0) {
        alert("E-Mail Required");
        return false;
    }
    if (phone.length == 0) {
        alert("Phone Required");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
    
    
    }
           
});
```

})

esto me funciona bien pero solo en el primer paso... en el js agrego el campo STREET. que pertenece al paso 2 pero como no se encuentra en el campo uno me indica que falta de llenar... espero haberme explicado.

Comment: estas usando alguna librería para el wizar? como haces el cambio de sección a sección? por que lo que yo haría es validar los campos por cada que presiono siguiente en cada sección

Comment: estoy usando jquery.steps.js no se si esto sirva como referencia

Answer (score 0):

Implementa este Ejemplo e identifica como se hace la validación, este ejemplo lo saque de la documentación del plugin

```
HTML
<form id="example-form" action="#">
    <div>
        <h3>Account</h3>
        <section>
            <label for="userName">User name *</label>
            <input id="userName" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="password">Password *</label>
            <input id="password" name="password" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="confirm">Confirm Password *</label>
            <input id="confirm" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
            <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
        </section>
        <h3>Profile</h3>
        <section>
            <label for="name">First name *</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="surname">Last name *</label>
            <input id="surname" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
            <label for="email">Email *</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input id="address" name="address" type="text">
            <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
        </section>
        <h3>Hints</h3>
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li>Foo</li>
                <li>Bar</li>
                <li>Foobar</li>
            </ul>
        </section>
        <h3>Finish</h3>
        <section>
            <input id="acceptTerms" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
        </section>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
JS
var form = $("#example-form");
form.validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password"
        }
    }
});
form.children("div").steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "section",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
});
```

por lo que logre entender la validación la hace con la clase required class="required" en los inputs a validar pero podría estar equivocado